# Possibility to specify Android launch activity parameters in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-activity

I'm using *IntelliJ IDEA v11.0.1*
In Run/Debug configuration of my Android application I can choose to "Launch default Activity", or any other activity from my project.

Is there any way to pass some custom `Intent` to choosed `Activity`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible from IDEA settings, however you can create another dummy activity that will send an intent to your desired activity and configure IDEA to run this dummy activity instead of the main one.